# Synchronize a loop within ray.remote

Tags: python-3.x, synchronization, ray

I have enormous remote function that is parallelized with ray but within it, there is a loop I really need to be executed serially - each iteration to be globally executed once and only once. So, my thinking was to have a mutex to synchronize executing threads

```
import ray    
ray.init ()

@ray.remote
def remote_function ():
    # misc calculation

    # loop to be synchronized
    lock (mutex)
    for i in range (gazillion):
        # do some prep work
        unlock (mutex)

        # do heavy work 

        lock (mutex)
    unlock (mutex)
```

This approach served me well in parallelized C code, but when I try googling mutexes and ray, essentially there is no info on the subject which, so I am suspecting that I am missing some key concept. My questions are - is this approach (locking/unlocking around loop start and stop) valid in python 3.7/ray, if not - is there a design pattern to be used instead and what mutex library should I use safely with ray?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ray's tasks are running within different processes. This means each of Ray tasks won't access other tasks memory, and you don't need to worry about synchronization.

For shared objects in the shared memory, they are read-only. So, you also don't need to worry about synchronizing the access to them.

Comment: You might only need locks within a loop only when you run multiple threads within a single Ray task using, for example, Python threading.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. But imagine that you need to delete many files or submit purchase order in a loop. This is something that must be serialized. Therefore, further googling gave me posix_ipc python implementation which is something I'll examine for this purpose.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want global level locking among processes. I think in this case. If you are planning to run Ray in a cluster of multi nodes, posix_ipc might not work (If you are using Ray only in a single node, it will be cool if you get it working in a single node and share it with the community :)). Another solution is just to use a separate actor that runs the part of the loop that must be synchronized (actor is running in a single process, and so there will be only one operation running at a time). But note that Ray currently doesn’t support exactly once message passing as of now.